# Laravel eloquent query with nested addSelect

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want to find the total sells of Individual Product and then sum sells of each product while fetching categories. I Know I can achieve this using laravel collection map and group by ,but I prefer using a single query.

```
Category::select("categories.*")
->whereHas("products")
->addSelect([
    'product_sells' => Product::select(DB::raw('sum(sells)'))
        ->whereColumn('category_id', 'categories.id')
        ->addSelect([
            'sells' => OrderDetail::select(DB::raw('sum(quantity)'))
                ->whereColumn('product_id', 'products.id')
        ])
])
->get();
```